# Chrome WebGL stops rendering when tab inactive

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, cesiumjs

I'm using Cesium JS which is a WebGL mapping framework.

When changing tabs on Chrome, after a while when switching back tabs to the Webgl page, there is a grey screen. I understand that Chrome disables Webgl rendering when the tab is inactive for a certain period.

How can I reset or start Webgl to start rendering again when the Tab is back to active?

I noticed when physically changing the browser window size this will re render webgl but I can't programmatically set window size on tab focus.

Answer (score 1):

Just check, may be context was losted, if you will see this log, just refresh youre context
`canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextlost", function(event) {
    console.log('lost');
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);` 
[good source for you](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingContextLost)